# Verificação de logado flutter

Tags: flutter

Quero fazer sistema de login opcional, entao algum botoes estao disponivel apenas para quem estiver logado mas ja tentei de todas as formas que conheço e nao consegui nada, tenho funçao para validaçao de sessiontoken, mas so quero que apareça botao de login se o user nao estiver cadastrado

```
Future<void> validateToken() async {
//recuperando o token que foi salvo localmente
String? sessionToken = await utilsServices.getLocalData(key: Storagekeys.sessionToken);

if (sessionToken == null) {
  Get.offAllNamed(PagesRoutes.homeRoute);
  return;
}

AuthResult result = await authRepository.validateToken(sessionToken);

result.when(
  sucess: (user) {
    this.user = user;
    saveTokenAndProceedToBase();
  },
  error: (message) {
    signOut();
  },
);
```

eu usei o mesmo codigo para verificar se esta logado para me retornar true ou false

```
    Future<bool?> isLogged() async {
    String? sessionToken = await utilsServices.getLocalData(key: Storagekeys.sessionToken);

        if (sessionToken == null) {
          Get.offAllNamed(PagesRoutes.homeRoute);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
```

porem nao consigo receber esse valor para mostrar ou nao o widget